# Parsing csv file with StreamReader and how can i pass it more than one search parameter

Tags: c#, search, streamreader

I have a program as seen below that is parsing a .csv file. IT opens up StreamReader and searches for keywords. I am trying to make it so that the users change the search parameters in a txt file not the actual program. Any suggestions on how i can get all of this code to work together would be very helpful.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;



namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
  class Test
 {
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dic = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt")
          .Select(l => l.Split(new[] { '=' }))
          .ToDictionary(s => s[0].Trim(), s => s[1].Trim()); 

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:/temp/ESMDLOG.csv"))
            {
                string currentLine;
                // currentLine will be null when the StreamReader reaches the end of file
                while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    // Search, case insensitive, if the currentLine contains the searched keyword
                    if (currentLine.IndexOf("I/RPTGEN", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(currentLine);
                        //Console.ReadLine();

                    }

                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The File could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly are you trying to search for here? Are you trying to find occurrences of the dictionary keys in the text file? A little better explanation of what you're trying to do would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list of another class, instead of a dictionary structure, to load the search configuration file content. This way you could store more than one search parameter as attributes of that class.

Then, after this, you will could easily use Linq to search items. (=